# INSERT $_POST values into MySQL table if some are empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have (in short) code like this:

```
...
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z) VALUES (".$_POST['a'].",".$_POST['b'].",\"".$_POST['c']."\")");
...
```

`a` is numeric value, `b` is numeric but empty in form and `c` is string value, which can be empty(there is no problem).

Tthen for MySQL it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z) VALUES (2,,"");
```

Problem is part of values, where is nothing like in `b`. Is there any solution to get it work? In database settings, or in PHP. I have big table and it is not possible to check every `$_POST` value.

thanks

Comment: please dont forget `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: mysql_ functions have been deprecated. you should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your query like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z) VALUES ('{$_POST['a']}', '{$_POST['b']}', '{$_POST['c']}')");
```

`''` will be passed if any of the post superglobal is empty.

Comment: zeros instead of null in database or in query?

Comment: zeros are in DB. in query there are `''`

Comment: I think may be you have used `numeric datatype` (like integer) for fields `x, y, z` and the `NULL` check box is not checked in table structure. Can you confirm that?

Comment: yes, I have used numeric datatypes (tinyint...), but I have tried check and uncheck NULL column in phpmyadmin before. still the same. but now it's ok, because I have converted all types to varchar. think, it's not problem.

Comment: Oh nice to know that your problem is solved. If my answer helped you consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: thanks for your solution. it extends my knowledge. I give you +1, but I can't accept the answer, because it is not exactly what I want. but again thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just test for `$_POST['b']` value, replacing it by `null` if empty or not set (adapt the solution to the empty value of `$_POST['b']` you're getting from your form):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z)
    VALUES (".$_POST['a'].",".((isset($_POST['b']) || $_POST['b']=="") ? $_POST['b'] : "NULL").",\"".$_POST['c']."\")");
```

As an aside, [don't use mysql_* extension](http://www.php.net/en/mysql_query) as they’re deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: there is no possibility to left it like `INSERT INTO table1 (x,y,z) VALUES (2,,"")` ? I have many columns and don't want to extend code if it is not necessary

Comment: Extra aside: Escape that input - PDO::quote() - or even better, prepared statement (which will eliminate your issue at the same time)

Comment: @koubin No you can't, because you cannot leave y value empty. You have to specifiy some value, at least NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert into set and create the query conditionally:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 set ";
$sql.= "x = '".mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['a']))."' ";
if (isset($_POST['b']) && ($_POST['b'] != '')){
    $sql.= ", y = '".mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['b']))."' ";
}
if (isset($_POST['c']) && ($_POST['c'] != '')){
    $sql.= ", z = '".mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['c']))."' ";
}

mysql_query($sql);
```

Also, try to use mysqli or PDO as others have pointed.